# Java Spring boot error in terminal but I never command to call alter table

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, eclipse, hibernate

I am doing a project with Hibernate and Spring. It seems that everything is going well, because it does map the classes to tables that I want, which are Product, User and Rent (A sales web page). I know that it maps them and adds objects because I can consult them in my local database.

However, the eclipse terminal throws me an error that I don't understand why

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table rent drop constraint FK39o7ymwe055dxo8vjt4d9py0e" via JDBC Statement

...

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relationship "rent" does not exist

Which makes sense up to this point because the tables have not been created. Then it does create the corresponding tables with the data I indicated.

But it is just that at no time do I alter drop or anything like that, in my import.sql file there are only the INSER TO for my database, hence I did add it.

So... What is this error due to? Thanks Does it really affect? Thank you!

My srpring version is v2.7.5

Comment: Show me the file application.properities

Comment: Sure @lavantho0508_java_dev


server.port=8090
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/ejemplo
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

Comment: move : spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/ejemplo 
to     : spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ejemplo

Comment: I get the same errors

@lavantho0508_java_dev